# How to include all relations in entity framework 6?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

```
Items = new ObservableCollection<CompanyContact>(
                        db.CompanyContacts
                        .Include(p => p.Facility)
                        .Include(p => p.Company)
                        .Include(p => p.Manager)
                        .OrderBy(s => s.Name)
                        .ToList<CompanyContact>()
                    );
```

Is there more elegant way to write that?
I want to include every relations in a table. Something like `IncludeAll`?
Thanks!

Comment: You may use `LazyLoadingEnabled = true` if your code wants all the entity be loaded. but loading it explicitly as provided by octavioccl in his answer is more preferable way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EF doen't have a method to include all the navigation properties. If you need to eager load all of them, you have no other choice but to call all the includes for each navigation property you want to load. A slightly more elegant solution could be using one of these extension methods:

```
public static class IQueryableExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<TEntity> GetAllIncluding<TEntity>(this IQueryable<TEntity> queryable, params string[] includeProperties)
    {
        return includeProperties.Aggregate(queryable, (current, includeProperty) => current.Include(includeProperty));
    }

    public static IQueryable<TEntity> GetAllIncludingWithFunc<TEntity>(this IQueryable<TEntity> queryable, params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] includeProperties)
    {
        return includeProperties.Aggregate(queryable, (current, includeProperty) => current.Include(includeProperty));
    }
}
```

Using the first method, for example, your query would be like this:

```
db.CompanyContacts.GetAllIncluding("Facility","Company", "Manager").OrderBy(s => s.Name).ToList();
```

Comment: Thak you for answer. it is sad... in your example there're strings. I don't like strings, what if I decide to rename something? Thank you for your time anyway

Comment: Hello @AnnaSmorodinova, you could use the second method: `db.CompanyContacts.GetAllIncluding(e=>e.Facility,e=>e.Company,e=>e.Manager);` this way if you change the name of the properties you will have compile errors in this call warning you the names have changed

Comment: Hello @octavioocl. Yep, I have it in my exmaple and I know about that. But thank you any way. It is a pitty, that there're no way to include all relations... Mine code could be much simpler in several places...